# Laravel URL route with utf-8 encoding

Tags: php, laravel, seo

I have some page that have urls very similar to Wikipedia:

```
http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Київ
```

The problem is that when I call laravel `route()` to get that url

```
route('myRouteName', 'Київ');
```

I get something like:

```
http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2
```

That is the encoded version of that parameters.

Now does Google or any other SE see these two urls as:

```
http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2
http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Київ
```

as the same or duplicate?

Comment: if you're happy with my answer below, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links are the same for Google. Here's the explanation from Google: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35653?hl=en

> Below is an example of a URL that uses a non-ASCII character (ü), as
>   well as a character that requires entity escaping (&):
>
> http://www.example.com/ümlat.html&q=name
>
> Below is that same URL,
>   ISO-8859-1 encoded (for hosting on a server that uses that encoding)
>   and URL escaped:
>
> http://www.example.com/%FCmlat.html&q=name

Comment: huh, SO can't parse links with non-ASCII characters :)

Answer (score 0):

Both URL-s will work in modern browsers and Google must be intelligent enough to show better SEO version. With wikipedia it shows http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Київ